# Optional argument in lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I have a function:

```
cost(X, model, reg = 1e-3, sparse)
```

And I need to pass this function to another one under the form:

```
f(X, model)
f(X, model, reg = reg)
```

I am using lambda to do this:

```
f = lambda X, model: cost(X, model, sparse = np.random.rand(10,10))
```

And python complains that lambda got an unexpected argument reg. How do I do this correctly?

If I do the other way:

```
f = lambda X, model, reg: cost(X, model, reg = reg, sparse = np.random.rand(10,10))
```

Then it's not working in the first case.

Comment: In a function call, keyword arguments must follow positional arguments. So I believe your `cost` function should be something similar to `cost(X, model, reg=1e-3, sparse='somethingelse'` or `cost(X, model, sparse, req=1e-3)`

Answer (score 39):

Lambda's take the same signature as regular functions, and you can give `reg` a default:

```
f = lambda X, model, reg=1e3: cost(X, model, reg=reg, sparse=np.random.rand(10,10))
```

What default you give it depends on what default the `cost` function has assigned to that same parameter. These defaults are stored on that function in the `cost.__defaults__` structure, matching the argument names. It is perhaps easiest to use the [`inspect.getargspec()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to introspect that info:

```
from inspect import getargspec

spec = getargspec(cost)
cost_defaults = dict(zip(spec.args[-len(defaults:], spec.defaults))
f = lambda X, model, reg=cost_defaults['reg']: cost(X, model, reg=reg, sparse=np.random.rand(10,10))
```

Alternatively, you could just pass on *any* extra keyword argument:

```
f = lambda X, model, **kw: cost(X, model, sparse=np.random.rand(10,10), **kw)
```

Comment: The default argument of the lambda should be the same as in the original function.

Comment: Any reason not to use `partial()` or am I missing something?

Comment: @dhke: you are; you need to execute the `np.random.rand()` call each time as you call `f()`, not just once when creating a `partial()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, lambda re-evaluates the argument whenever executed!

Comment: it's not some special lambda thing -  he explicitly wants `rand() re-executed`.

Answer (score 7):

have you tried something like

`f = lambda X, model, **kw: cost(X, model, sparse = np.random.rand(10,10), **kw)`

then `reg` (and any other named argument you want to pass through (other than sparse)) should work fine.